# Create dynamics names for UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, init, alloc

All is in my title, i want to create some dynamics names, to allocate some differents UIViews but randomly. For example, i want to make :

```
Level1 * level1view = [[Level1 alloc] init];
```

So i try to make some NSString like this :

```
ClasseMap = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level%i", Map];
NomMap = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%iview", NumeroMap];
id nouveau = NSClassFromString(ClasseMap);
nouveau * ViewTest;
ViewTest = [self valueForKey:NomMap];
ViewTest  = [[nouveau alloc] init];
```

But it gives me : Use of undeclared identifier 'ViewTest'. How could i fix it please ? How could i get access to some variables (for example, level1view.example = YES;) ?

Thanks for your help ! =)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226611/how-to-instantiate-an-object-of-class-from-string-in-objective-c

Comment: But how to, for the name, like in my example "leve1view", because i put "NSClassFromString(ClasseMap) * NSClassFromString(NomMap) = [[NSClassFromString(ClasseMap) alloc] init];" but it's not working :(

Comment: I've edited my question because it was not so clear, but not duplicate :(

Answer (score 0):

why dont you rather keep an array of views instead?

```
int Map = 0;
int NumeroMap = 1;

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//add your views (levels?) to the array
[array addObject:someUIView];
[array addObject:someOtherUIView];

//now you can use your indexes to access the views you want
UIView *yourView = [array objectAtIndex:Map];
UIView *anotherView = [array objectAtIndex:NumeroMap];
```

i think what you are trying to do is not the way to go about things.

Comment: I can't take a rather of view because i'm creating an infinity game, so the algorithm choose which view he want to print, but they are not declared before (printing matters)